# Is this a best practice to make API call in Express 4.0

Tags: node.js, rest, express, response

The application is making API request to the server and returning back the response received. Here would like to understand

(i) Is it right way to make API call and receive response from the server.

(ii) if return statement passing back the value is right way

The module is called as

```
str = apiRequest(search, lang);
```

And the module is

```
var https = require('https');

function apiRequest(search, lang) {

   var options = {
       host: 'localhost:8080',
       path: '/api?search=' + search + '&lang=' + lang
   };


   function resData(res) {
       console.log("Status Code : ", res.statusCode);

       var str = '';

       res.on('data', function (chunk) {
           str += chunk;
       });

       res.on('end', function () {
           return JSON.parse(str);   // Is this a right way to return data
       });

       res.on('error', function(e) {
           console.error(e);
       });
   }

   https.get(options, resData).end();
};
```

Comment: This is not express. `return` in a async function is wrong. You clearly didn't tried to run this code either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work. I will comment the relevant parts below.

Instead of having this in `apiRequest`:

```
function apiRequest(search, lang) {
   function resData(res) {
       // ...
       res.on('end', function () {
           return JSON.parse(str);   // Is this a right way to return data
       });
       // ...
   }
   https.get(options, resData).end();
}
```

and calling it with:

```
str = apiRequest(search, lang);
```

You should either pass a **callback** or return a **promise**.

### Using callbacks

Your `apiRequest` function can take an additional argument, a callback:

```
function apiRequest(search, lang, callback) {
   function resData(res) {
       // ...
       res.on('end', function () {
           callback(null, JSON.parse(str));
       });
       res.on('error', function(e) {
           console.error(e);
           callback(e);
       });
       // ...
   }
   https.get(options, resData).end();
}
```

Now you can use it as:

```
apiRequest(search, lang, function (error, str) {
    if (err) {
        // you have error
    } else {
        // you have your str here
    }
});
```

### Using promises

Your `apiRequest` function can return a promise:

```
function apiRequest(search, lang, callback) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     function resData(res) {
       // ...
       res.on('end', function () {
           resolve(JSON.parse(str));
       });
       res.on('error', function(e) {
           console.error(e);
           reject(e);
       });
       // ...
     }
     https.get(options, resData).end();
   }
}
```

Now you can use it as:

```
apiRequest(search, lang)
.then(function (str) {
    // you have your str here
})
.catch(function (err) {
    // you have error
});
```

This is not tested so there might be some minor mistakes but that is the general idea. When I find some errors I'll update the answer.

### Summary

To sum it up, there are two styles that you can use to compose asynchronous functions like that: callbacks or promises. You will not be able to just return the data because `return` is fundamentally synchronous - you have to have something to return right away - unless what you return is a promise that can get resolved or rejected later.

### Parsing JSON

What should also keep in mind that you should always run `JSON.parse()` inside a `try {} catch {} block` to handle errors of incorrect JSON or otherwise the entire app could crash. `JSON.parse()` throws exceptions on bad input. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826384/calling-a-json-api-with-node-js/39612292#39612292) for more info.

This will additionally complicate your code but you can avoid that complication and make it even simpler by using the `request` module - see updates below.

## Simpler examples

### Callbacks

To have a working example that is simpler and your don't have to manually parse JSON, consider this code that I just wrote, based on your example but calling a GitHub API so it can be tested by everyone - it prints someone's website given his GitHub nickname but otherwise works similarly to your code:

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');

function apiRequest(search, callback) {

  var options = {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + search,
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
  };

  function resData(err, res, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      callback(res.statusCode);
    } else {
      // data is already parsed as JSON:
      callback(null, data.blog);
    }
  }

  request.get(options, resData);

}

apiRequest('rsp', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Data:', data);
  }
});
```

This is an example using callbacks.

### Promises

And here is an example using promises:

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');

function apiRequest(search, callback) {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var options = {
      url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + search,
      json: true,
      headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
    };

    function resData(err, res, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        reject(res.statusCode);
      } else {
        // data is already parsed as JSON:
        resolve(data.blog);
      }
    }

    request.get(options, resData);

  });

}

apiRequest('rsp')
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Data:', data);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
  });
```

### Simplified

It can be simplified even further by using fat arrow functions and anonymous functions and object literals:

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');

function apiRequest(search, callback) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get({
      url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + search,
      json: true,
      headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
    }, (err, res, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        reject(res.statusCode);
      } else {
        resolve(data.blog);
      }
    });
  });

}

apiRequest('rsp')
  .then(data => console.log('Data:', data))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));
```

### More info

You can see some other answers where I explain the difference between callbacks and promises and how to use the together in more detail, which you may find helpful:

- [A detailed explanation on how to use callbacks and promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659829/how-can-i-chain-these-functions-together-with-promises/39660257#39660257)
- [Explanation on how to use promises in complex request handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691647/nodejs-express-and-promises-not-doing-what-i-expect/39691872#39691872)
- [An explanation of what a promise really is, on the example of AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)
- [An explanation on how to handle errors in callbacks and promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764599/how-can-i-return-status-inside-the-promise/39765591#39765591)

Comment: Thanks rsp, you really explained it nicely. I was not sure if I wanted to use callback. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoelDivekar I'm glad it helped. See also the updates to my answer with "Simpler examples" where I show how you can use the `request` module so you don't have to concatenate the chunks of data and parse the JSON yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot rsp. This is really helpful. Do you suggest promise is a way to go ahead ?