# Store database attribute in var

Tags: node.js, sqlite, callback

I have the following code:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');

db.serialize(function() {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counts (key TEXT, value INTEGER)");
    db.run("INSERT INTO counts (key, value) VALUES (?, ?)", "counter", 0);
});


var getValue = function(res){
    db.get("SELECT value FROM counts", function(err, row){
        res.json({ "count" : row.value });
        return;
    });
};

console.log(getValue);
```

Output is

```
[Function]
```

But should be json. What am I doing wrong?
I took the example from http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=3152

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did my post below answer your question? If not then please comment so I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Oh yes it did answer my question. I didn't still get the hang of it but I'll get there. I solved the problem in python (it was an exercise) and am planning to read more into it once I'm out of deadlines ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course `getValue` is a function, because few lines before you wrote:

```
var getValue = function(res){
   // ...
};
```

so now, when you write:

```
console.log(getValue);
```

it tells you that it's a function.

What you probably want is:

```
getValue({json: console.log});
```

or maybe:

```
getValue({json: data => console.log(data.count)});
```

if you want to display that value from an object passed to `res.json`, **if** you have a `db.get()` function that returns one row in that format - make sure that you're using it correctly in the first place. But keep in mind that this is asynchronous so you won't be able to store it in a variable immediately.

Simplifying your example a little bit, you can do:

```
asyncFunc('args', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Value:', data);
  }
});
```

but you won't be able to return that value, because returning a simple value is a synchronous process. What you can return is a promise:

```
function getPromise() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    asyncFunc('args', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

that you can then use like this:

```
getPromise()
  .then(value => console.log('Value:', value))
  .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));
```

If you don't know why is that then you can see some other answers where I explain how to get data from asynchronous function calls which you may find helpful:

- [A detailed explanation on how to use callbacks and promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659829/how-can-i-chain-these-functions-together-with-promises/39660257#39660257)
- [Explanation on how to use promises in complex request handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691647/nodejs-express-and-promises-not-doing-what-i-expect/39691872#39691872)
- [An explanation of what a promise really is, on the example of AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)
- [An explanation on how to handle errors in callbacks and promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764599/how-can-i-return-status-inside-the-promise/39765591#39765591)

Answer (score 0):

You did not *call* the getValue function.  Call it like this: `getValue()`.  But that function returns null.

You will need to start with a more basic example.  First learn about function calls, then when you have that down move on to other things.