# Asynchronous function - node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a question about asynchronous function. Here my function "My_function":

```
 function My_function (my_name, callback){
      stmt = db.prepare ("SELECT number_table1 from my_table1 WHERE user=?");
        stmt.bind(my_name);
        stmt.get(function(error,row){
          if(error){
            throw err;
          }
          else{
            if(row){
              callback(number_table1);
            }
            else{
              console.log("error");
            }
           }
       });
    }
```

Work fine but I have 2 tables and I need do other query and I need add two numbers so... in my function I need do too this query:

```
stmt = db.prepare ("SELECT number_table2 from my_table2 WHERE user=?");
```

and finally return back in my callback "number_table1 + number_table2".
Somebody know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

In cases like your's I like to use the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module, because the code will be more legible. Example:

```
var async = require('async');

function My_function(my_name, callback) {
  var stmt = db.prepare("SELECT number_table1 from my_table1 WHERE user=?");
  stmt.bind(my_name);
  stmt.get(function (error, row) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error, null);
    } else {
      if (row) {
        callback(null, number_table1);
      } else {
        callback(new Error("row not found"), null);
      }
    }
  });
}

//if you need the results in a specific order, you can use "series" instead of "parallel".
async.parallel(
  //array of functions
  [
    function (callback) {
      My_function('firstName', callback);
    },
    function (callback) {
      My_function('secondName', callback);
    }
  ],

  //results when all functions ends
  //the results array will equal [number_table1, number_table2], but the order can be different, because of the parallelism
  function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      //handle the err 
    } else {
      //do something
    }
  }
);
```

Docs:

- http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel or
- http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series

Comment: Thanks for reply me Victor but I need correct order in my datas because I need to do more complex operations :S

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the functions so that you can be sure both their results are ready before calling back. You can do this using promises: https://www.promisejs.org/

- Make two regular functions (no callbacks), one for each query (function1, function2)
- Make both return a promise
- Then you can do

  ```
  function My_function(my_name) {
      var value1;
      function1(my_name)
          .then(function(resultFromFunction1) {
              value1 = resultFromFunction1;
              return function2(my_name);
          })
          .then(function(resultFromFunction2) {
              var result = value1 + resultFromFunction2;
              return result;
          });
      }
  }
  ```

Make sure to catch errors and handle different outcomes, what  I presented is its simplest form.

**Update**

Here is an example of a function doing a query and returning a promise

```
function1 = function(user) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if(err) {
                reject ({status : false, message : "Error in connection database"});
            } else {
                connection.query('SELECT number_table1 from my_table1 WHERE user=?', [user], function(err, rows){
                    connection.release();
                    if(!err) {
                        resolve ({status: true, message: rows});
                    } else {
                        reject ({status: false, message: err});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Aidin, thanks for reply me but, I'm new using asynchronous programming and do not understand too well. I'm not sure how to return a promise from my function. If you don't mind could you please write how would it be all the code?
For return a promise in my function will be like this:

function function1() {
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            ...
            resolve(result);
        });
}

Thanks in advane!! :)

Comment: @Tecnico I am quite new to but here is an example of how I do it. I am sorry but at the moment I cannot give a better example. Anyone who knows of a more relevant example is free to edit.

Comment: @Tecnico I asked a promise question recently myself because I did not know how to do it. You can read it here. The answer is really good so maybe you can get something from it as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691647/nodejs-express-and-promises-not-doing-what-i-expect

Comment: OK! Thanks you very much I will see your post. Other question, could you please check the function "My_function"? Is possible that something is wrong?

Comment: @Tecnico Sorry, I am not very familiar with that kind of writing. But I see something weird, `callback(number_table1);`. What is `number_table1`? It is not defined anywhere. Did you mean to return `row`?

Comment: @Tecnico or do you mean the `My_function`in my code?

Comment: @Tecnico There was a `;` in my code before the second `.then` which should not have been there

Answer (score -1):

Make the table names function parameters.  Convert that function to use async/await or promise.  Use Promise.all to run both queries.