# How do I authenticate with Node.js + Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

With the following code I'm not able to authenticate with a MongoDB database, which already has a Users schema and users associated with it and I was wondering how I would make sure that auth returned isAuth?:

```
exports.auth = function(username, password, session) {
    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        var isAuth = username === data['username'] & password === data['password'];

         if (isAuth) {
             session.isAuthenticated = isAuth;
             session.user = {username: username};
         }

         return isAuth;
    });
};
```

Comment: For security I would suggest you try out [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) instead of implementing your own auth module.

Comment: ^ Listen to @chridam. Authentication is a horrible thing to get wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as others have already pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't implement your own authentication logic if you don't know what you're doing. You can use [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) for that.

Now, to the code you provided. There are several problems here.

The first thing that comes to mind is that you use:

```
var isAuth = username === data['username'] & password === data['password'];
```

instead of:

```
var isAuth = username === data['username'] && password === data['password'];
```

But this is just a typo. Now, to more fundamental stuff.

You cannot return the `isAuth` variable because who are you going to return it to? If you think that it will get returned to the caller of `exports.auth` then you're wrong - the `exports.auth()` will return long before the `return isAuth;` is ever run.

Also, if yu check for error with `if (err)` then put the code that should be run in the case of success in the `else` block o otherwise it will also be run on error with undefined variables that may crash your program.

You need to either add an additional argument to your function which is a callback:

```
exports.auth = function(username, password, session, callback) {
    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            var isAuth = username === data.username && password === data.password;
            if (isAuth) {
                session.isAuthenticated = isAuth;
                session.user = {username: username};
            }
            callback(null, isAuth);
        }
    });
};
```

or to return a promise from your `exports.auth` function (but directly from your `exports.auth` function, not some other callback inside).

Using the above version you can call it with:

```
auth(username, password, session, function (isAuth) {
  // you have your isAuth here
});
```

The other option would be to use promises. You can see some other answers where I explain the difference between callbacks and promises and how to use them together in more detail, which may be helpful to you in this case:

- [A detailed explanation on how to use callbacks and promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659829/how-can-i-chain-these-functions-together-with-promises/39660257#39660257)
- [Explanation on how to use promises in complex request handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691647/nodejs-express-and-promises-not-doing-what-i-expect/39691872#39691872)
- [An explanation of what a promise really is, on the example of AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)

But first you need to get comfortable with callbacks.

Also, **never** store the passwords in cleartext in the database. Seriously, use some other solution that works like Passport. I wrote the answer to explain the process of using callbacks, not to endorse the idea of using authentication in that particular way. You have been warned.

Comment: I changed the '&' to '&&' as suggested, but instead of [0,1] I now get [false, true], so it's made no difference. What I need is for the outer function to return isAuth.

Comment: I would also point out that it's a horrible, horrible idea to store and compare clear text passwords vice using a salted one-way hash.

Comment: @Paul, you're 100% right. I wrote the answer to explain the callbacks mechanism not to endorse this particular way of storing passwords which is of course unacceptable. I added a warning about it at the end. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html) comes to mind :)