# promise call separate from promise-resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm not so familiar with promises.
I would like hide promise-implementation from promise-call.

Example:

```
function findFriends(req, res) {

    const promiseFriend  = MyFriendes.find({}).exec(); //call promise

    if(friends.length===0){
        logger.warn('No friendsavailible');
    }else if(friends === undefined){
        res.status(500).json({
            error: 'INTERNAL ERROR'
        });
    }else{
        res.status(200).json({
            friends: friends
        });
    }
}
```

and I will resolve my promise within same file but not 
at same function, where I call this promise.

```
 promiseFriend  
        .then(function(friends){
            return friends;
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            logger.error({error:err});
        });
```

Now, I get, that "promiseFriend" is undefined.
How can I separate promise-call from promise-resolution?

Comment: Could you post more code? Where do you call `findFriends` and where do you call promise exactly? 

One thing I could tell you about the promises - as long as you don't call 'then' somewhere in your code, promise won't be resolved. And after resolution you could call the same `then` as many times as you want and it will return the same values (already resolved).

promiseFriend being undefined has nothing to do with promise - it just means that in the place where you call the promise this variable is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define a promise in a function and use it somewhere else then first of all you need to return the promise from that function, which you're not doing in your code. Then you need to actually call that function which you are also not doing. And finally you need to use a `then` callback on the returned value, which you are not doing in this case as well.

There is no point in saving the promise in a local variable `promiseFriend` that is scoped to this function. There is also no point to return a value in your `then` callback: `.then(function (friends) { return friends; })` - I have no idea what have tried to do here.

I suppose that `findFriends` is supposed to be a route handler for Express. If so then make sure that you send a response in every case (which you don't do for `friends.length===0`). Also, you need to actually add a `then` handler to the saved promise if you want to act when it's resolved. Right now you don't even have `friends` defined in your function. Also add a `catch` handlers and also send a response for that case.

Then you might return the promise from your function but not if it is a route handler, it doesn't make sense. You can return a promise from a function:

```
function x() {
  return MyFriendes.find({}).exec();
}
```

and then use it:

```
x().then(friends => ...).catch(error => ...);
```

but you cannot use return values if you don't return it, you can't use undefined variables as if they were defined, and you actually need to consider who is your return value returned to.

I suggest that you learn how Node actually works because it seems that you have copied and pasted some random code, joined it together and expect that it does what you want without actually trying to understand it.

To get a better understanding on the asynchronous nature of Node that is giving this execution order here, see those answers:

- [A detailed explanation on how to use callbacks and promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659829/how-can-i-chain-these-functions-together-with-promises/39660257#39660257)
- [Explanation on how to use promises in complex request handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691647/nodejs-express-and-promises-not-doing-what-i-expect/39691872#39691872)
- [An explanation of what a promise really is, on the example of AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)
- [An explanation of callbacks, promises and how to access data returned asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764599/how-can-i-return-status-inside-the-promise/39765591#39765591)

Don't try to write Node programs before you understand the concept of function calls, return values, callbacks and in this case promises.

Comment: thx. for explanation. I just saw only easy examples of promises, but when i will be more complicated, i would like to see, how could it be designed.