# Unable to run js command after MySQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, ibm-cloud

I want to fetch a variable from MySQL table and based on the variable value open my web app window. I coded the MySQL connection query at server end of the app. So when the server connection is established the above mentioned flow could happen.
But after fetching the variable value, the code doesn't run forward and in debug mode the cursor ends on being the return value of y. 
Someone please help to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config({silent: true});

var server = require('./app');
var port = process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8000;
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

var def = function(){
server.listen(port, function() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  console.log('Server running on port: %d', port);
  return;
});
}

var X;
global.x = X;

var mysql = require('mysql');
var mysqlPool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'emp',
  debug    : true
});

var abc = function(){
 mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) { 
  connection.query("select exp from empid where id= 12345", function(err, rows){
  if(err) {
    throw err;
   } else {
    var y = rows[0].exp;
   }
  //connection.release(); 
  *return y;*
  });
 });
}

def();
abc();

if(abc > 2) {
  window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
}
```

Comment: are you getting value at rows[0].exp; ?

Comment: yes i am getting the value in y as required. it's just the code is not running after return y statement which I intended to

Comment: Thanks baao & rsp that worked but now I have another issue

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the value from the callback because your `abc()` function returns way before your `return` statement is run - note that the `return` returns from the function in which it was used, not some outer function.

You can return a promise or use a callback if you want to use that value outside of the DB query handler.

See those answers for details:

- [Return Promise result instead of Promise in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719024/return-promise-result-instead-of-promise-in-nodejs/41719314#41719314)
- [Return value in function from a promise block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785769/return-value-in-function-from-a-promise-block/40785901#40785901)
- [A detailed explanation on how to use callbacks and promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659829/how-can-i-chain-these-functions-together-with-promises/39660257#39660257)
- [Explanation on how to use promises in complex request handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691647/nodejs-express-and-promises-not-doing-what-i-expect/39691872#39691872)
- [An explanation of what a promise really is, on the example of AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)
- [An explanation of callbacks, promises and how to access data returned asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764599/how-can-i-return-status-inside-the-promise/39765591#39765591)

Comment: Thanks rsp that helped but now I have another issue. The socket is closing after the url is opened. I want socket to be opened so that i can continuously monitor DB and pop up url based on DB value. Please help. Thanks.var abc = function(callback){
 mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) { 
  connection.query(qry, function(err, rows){
  if(err) {
    throw err;
   } else {
    var y = rows[0].exp;
    console.log(y);
    callback(y);
   }
  });
 });
}

def();
abc(function(y){
console.log(y);
if(y > 2) {
  opn('http://www.w3schools.com');
}
});